# Solve the integral $\int_0^{x} \frac{v^{1/n}}{(1+v)^{(n+1)/n}} dv$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $x$ be some positive number and $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$. I would like to solve the following integral:
$$\int_0^{x} \frac{v^{1/n}}{(1+v)^{(n+1)/n}} dv$$

Comment: This looks like a beta function.

Comment: First idea:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space\text{n}}\left(x\right):=\int_0^x\frac{\text{v}^\frac{1}{\text{n}}}{\left(1+\text{v}\right)^\frac{1+\text{n}}{\text{n}}}\space\text{d}\text{v}=\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+\text{v}}\cdot\left(\frac{\text{v}}{1+\text{v}}\right)^\frac{1}{\text{n}}\space\text{d}\text{v}\tag1$$

Substitute $\text{u}:=1+\text{v}$:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space\text{n}}\left(x\right)=\int_1^{1+x}\frac{1}{\text{u}}\cdot\left(\frac{\text{u}-1}{\text{u}}\right)^\frac{1}{\text{n}}\space\text{d}\text{u}\tag2$$

Comment: Is this last integral a known integral?

Comment: It was indeed a Beta function - See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is expressible in terms of the [incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function). Set $$y=\dfrac{v}{1+v}=1-\dfrac{1}{1+v}$$ so $dy=\dfrac{dv}{(1+v)^2}=(1-y)^2dv$ and $dv=(1-y)^{-2}dy$. Since $1+v=\dfrac{1}{1-y}$ and $$v=\dfrac{1}{1-y}-1=\dfrac{y}{1-y},$$ the integral becomes $$\int_0^{\frac{x}{1+x}}y^{1/n}(1-y)^{-1}dy=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\text{B}(\frac{x}{1+x};\,\frac{n+1}{2n},\,\epsilon).$$

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use this:
$$dx={1\over a}d(ax)$$
Maybe I've been wrong.
$$\int_0^x{v^{1\over n}\over {(1+v)}^{{n+1}\over n}}dv = \int_0^x{v^{1\over n}\over {(1+v)}^{{1}\over n}{(1+v)}}dv = \int_0^x{v^{1\over n}\over {(1+v)}^{{1}\over n}{(1+v)}} \cdot (1+v)\cdot d({v\over 1+v})$$
$$\int_0^x{v^{1\over n}\over {(1+v)}^{{1}\over n}}d({v\over 1+v})={({v\over {1+v}})^{{1\over n}+1}\over {{1\over n}+1}}\biggr|_0^x={n({x\over {1+x}})^{{1+n}\over n}\over {1+n}}$$

Comment: $d(ax)=a\,dx$ only holds if $a$ isn’t a function of $x$. But $1+v$ is certainly a function of $v$, so you can’t absorb it into $dv$. Hence this approach doesn’t succeed. (You _could_ attempt $a\,dx=d(ax)-x \frac{da}{dx}dx$ instead, since this applies when $a$ depends on $x$. But in that case you’re just doing integration between parts.)